# Why does this Decryption not work?

Tags: .net, vb.net, encryption

The code presented within the stars is not working. I'm trying to decrypt an encrypted form, but failing miserably.

```
    Dim SmpleFile As String ' the encrypted text
    Dim tf As String = ""
    Dim plaintext As String = ""
    Dim Factor As Integer = Val(lblOffsetFac.Text)
    Dim cyphertextch As Integer

    SmpleFile = lblEncdText.Text

    For Each ch As Char In SmpleFile
        'This means the spaces wont change
        If ch = " " Then
            cyphertextch = 32
        Else 'If the character doesnt = " "
            'This means that if the number is less
            'than 33, 94 will be added to make the
            'character convertable and correct.

            cyphertextch = Asc(ch)
            cyphertextch = cyphertextch + Factor

            If cyphertextch < 33 Then
                cyphertextch = cyphertextch + 94

            End If

        End If
        **plaintext += Chr(cyphertextch)**

    Next
    'This displays the newly decyped textfile which is the same as sample.txt
    lblDecdText.Text = plaintext
    lblDecdText.Visible = True
End Sub
```

I was told i wasn't allowed to shout but if i could, this would all be in capitals to express my desperation

Comment: What about it isn't working? What error are you getting?

Comment: You tagged VB.NET and VBA, but `+=` operator does not exist in VBA. Which language are you really using?

Comment: I'm using visual basic

Comment: Please include inputs (cyphertext and factor) and the exact problem you have.  Error or invalid output?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You've provided the code, but haven't shown what's supposed to be wrong with it. Please [edit] your question provide example inputs, outputs and expected outputs.

Answer (score 1):

You should either use `plaintext = plaintext & Chr(cyphertextch)`. [`&` is an operator in VB.NET to perform string concatenation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/te2585xw.aspx). Alternatively you can also use [`StringBuilder.append`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yet24s7b%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).